# How to specify the submodule branch in gitlab-ci?

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, continuous-deployment, gitlab-ci

How to specify branch in .gitlab-ci.yml for a submodule (different repo) in gitlab-ci?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't. You specify it in the [`.gitmodules`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitmodules) file of the project you are building.

```
[submodule "MyRepo"]
    path = MyRepo
    url = https://github.com/vendor/MyRepo.git
    branch = master
```

Comment: This does't work for me. I have this in my `.gitsubmodules` file, but when i push to gitlab the most recent commit of any branch is used

Comment: @ZachSmith the file should be called `.gitmodules`

Comment: Yes.... indeed it should (and is). That was a typo in the question. Apologies. I've added an answer below

Answer (score 4):

Along with @stefan's answer to this question. You also have to tell Git to only look at the specified branch for the latest commit. `git submodule update` seems to always fetch the latest commit regardless of the branch. Doing `git submodule update --remote` seems to force git to focus on the branch you specify in the `.gitmodules` file.

So in your `.gitmodules` files, as @stefen mentions:

```
[submodule "MyRepo"]
    path = MyRepo
    url = https://github.com/vendor/MyRepo.git
    branch = master
```

Then in your GitLab `.gitlab-ci.yml` file, you need to specify to only look at the configured branch when setting up submodules. My file includes this `before_script`:

```
# GitLab CI provides a variable "GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY" that sets up submodules automatically
# But then branch tracking doesn't work (doesn't seem to allow for specifying the --remote) flag
before_script:
 - git submodule sync --recursive
 - git submodule update --init --remote --recursive
```

According to documentation, this `before_script` is the same functionality as provided by `GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY` (except that I can add the `--remote` flag to the `before_script`): https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#git-submodule-strategy