# How to specify GitLab's CI submodule setup to ONLY use commits on the master branch?

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have an automated deployment pipeline setup via GitLab's integrated CI:

(1) I have a CentOS server with a GitLab runner (using the `shell` executor)

(2) I have a repository that contains a `.gitlab-ci.yml` file and a `.gitsubmodules` file specifying two repositories

(3) My `.gitsubmodules` file specifies the `master` branch of each submodule, and looks like this:

```
[submodule "api"]
    path = api
    url = ../api.git
    branch = master
[submodule "client"]
    path = client
    url = ../client.git
    branch = master
```

I am working directly in the submodules directories (`./client` and `./api`).

I would like the parent directory (i.e. the 'deployment' repository that contains the two submodules) to really only reflect changes to the master branches of the submodules. However I find this is not happening (if this helps... I changed the `.submodules` file to have `branch = master` AFTER working with the repo for a while.

I find when I push the deployment project to GitLab that the submodules setup includes the most recent commit of ANY branch, and not the master branch as I want.

I have this in the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file to specify how submodules are setup:

```
GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: recursive
```

What am I doing wrong? i.e. How can I specify in the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file or otherwise that I ONLY want to use the master branch of the submodules?

This answer: [How to specify the submodule branch in gitlab-ci?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46177836/how-to-specify-the-submodule-branch-in-gitlab-ci) doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I can tell the top level repo to look at the latest commit on a submodule's particular branch via specifying `--remote`:

```
git submodule update --remote --recursive
```

That is according to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18797720/3114742

However I feel that this is a little hacky and I'd like a better way if there is one