# How to specify git submodule branch in gitlab-ci when merging to another dev-environment

Tags: git, gitlab-ci, git-submodules

I want to modify a git submodule to be on a specific branch in my gitlab-ci.

Example:

- Developer A pushes repository `RepoA` dependent on `SubmoduleA` to Gitlab
- Opens a merge-request to merge `RepoA` `dev-branch` into `staging-branch`
- We test the code in `staging-branch` of `RepoA` with `staging-branch` of `SubmoduleA`
- We merge the `SubmoduleA` `staging-branch` into `main`
- Then we merge `RepoA` `staging-branch` into `main`

Problem:
`RepoA` submodule `SubmoduleA` config still uses `SubmoduleA` `staging-branch` instead of the `main` branch.

This is not solvable by changing the `.gitmodules` file on the dev-branch as advised here:
[How to specify the submodule branch in gitlab-ci?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46177836/how-to-specify-the-submodule-branch-in-gitlab-ci)

Therefore we need a solution to change the submodule branch dependent on the environment or $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH.

What I tried:

- Set `GIT_SUBMODULE_UPDATE_FLAGS` to `--remote --force --recursive`
- Use `git checkout` but HEAD is detached at main (if no branch in `.gitmodules` is given

```
$ git branch -a
* (HEAD detached at cc939d4)
  main
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/main
  remotes/origin/main
```

The only "workaround" I found is to delete the existing submodules after remembering their names, then re-add them with a branch which is not clean at all.